# Django Form Not updating

Tags: python, django, forms, refresh

I'm trying to update a form in Django. I have the following:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class List(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_list', args=[self.id])

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default = '')
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, default = None)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from lists.models import Item

EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR = "You can't have an empty list item"
class ItemForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('text',)
        widgets ={
            'text' : forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
                    'placeholder': 'Enter a to-do item',
                    'class': 'form-control input-lg',
            }),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'text' : { 'required': EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR }
        }
```

I'm not seeing any changes in the forms.py now that it has been loaded. What I mean is, the page displays the form find, but if I attempt to change, for example, the placeholder value::

```
            'placeholder': 'Enter a to-do item OR DON'T!',
```

The input box doesn't show any changes once the page loads. Is there a manage.py command I need to run? Or some other migration?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are saying that you don't see the changes in your browser. So i suggest you clear your browser's cache and reload the page. If you go to the manage section of the browser developer tools and select the option to not store cache when dev tools is activated. Cache can be a pain when you forget it exists.

Answering your question at the bottom: you don't need to reload the `manage.py runserver` or use another command. The django automatically reloads the server (the simple one used in development) with every change in the python files.